# OpenCL support for Nvidia GTX 295

Tags: opencl, nvidia

Does OpenCL support for Nvidia GTX 295 exists for Linux or is expected in the near future?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Linux distro is supported: yes. Download the latest drivers from the [NVIDIA website](http://www.nvidia.com/drivers).

Answer (score 0):

Try asking on the [nVidia developer forums](http://developer.nvidia.com) - there are nVidia engineers on the forums who can help with this kind of question, especially if it's in regard to as-yet-unreleased software.